# Wrapping one function inside another

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the `jquery.webui-popover.js` plugin. I have got it to work with the following code:

```
$('.button').webuiPopover({
    placement: 'bottom',
    title: 'Link Item to Button',
    content: '123',
    animation: 'pop',
    delay: {
        show: null,
        hide: 300
    },
});
```

However I am trying to wrap it in my own function as I call it on multiple elements at different times in my code. I have changed it to:

```
function AddCreatePopoverBinding(element) {

    element.webuiPopover({
        placement: 'bottom',
        title: 'Link Item to Button',
        content: '123',
        animation: 'pop',
        delay: {
            show: null,
            hide: 300
        },
    });
}
```

And then call it further down in my code using:

```
$('.button').AddCreatePopoverBinding();
```

However I am getting the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).AddCreatePopoverBinding is not a function

What am I doing wrong? I tried using a .each statement to call the function but that also failed.

Comment: You should declare function on jQuery prototype: `$.fn.AddCreatePopoverBinding = function(){ return this.webuiPopover({...});};` And calling it as you do: `$('.button').AddCreatePopoverBinding();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As *A. Wolff* says, you'd need what is known as a [jQuery Plugin](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/) to do this, i.e. add your function into the jQuery namespace:

```
$.fn.AddCreatePopoverBinding = function() {
    return this.webuiPopover({
        placement: 'bottom',
        title: 'Link Item to Button',
        content: '123',
        animation: 'pop',
        delay: {
            show: null,
            hide: 300
        },
    });
}
```

That should also allow for [chaining](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/#chaining):

```
var button = $('.button').AddCreatePopoverBinding();
console.log(button.text());
```

Comment: Now i should admit, i don't see any reason why OP isn't calling directly `$('.button').webuiPopover(options);` ?!

Comment: Perhaps they are wrapping the `webuiPopover` with some other repeated functionality and trying to keep things DRY. Who knows :)

Answer (score 1):

You can call your function like this:

```
AddCreatePopoverBinding($('.button'));
```

Comment: Shouldn't be the parameter a jQuey-Object instead of a string ? So like this `AddCreatePopoverBinding($('.button'));` ?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I forgot it ;)